# JavaScript: разные методы получения значений по клику элемента с помощью addEventListener

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите как лучше использовать `addEventListener` при клике на `input`

Есть HTML:

```
<div id="browsers">
   <p><b>Браузер:</b><Br>
      <input type="radio" name="browser" value="ie"> Internet Explorer<Br>
      <input type="radio" name="browser" value="opera"> Opera<Br>
      <input type="radio" name="browser" value="firefox" checked="checked"> Firefox<Br>
   </p>
</div>
```

Два метода определения значения value для нажатого `input`.

**Первый**:

```
browsers = document.getElementById('browsers');
var check = browsers.querySelectorAll('input[name="browser"]');

for (var i=0;i<check.length;i++){
    check[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        console.log(this.value);
    });
}
```

**Второй**:

```
browsers = document.getElementById('browsers');
browsers.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    elem = e.target.value;
       if(elem){
         console.log(elem);
       }
   })
```

Везде вижу только **первый способ**, то есть выборка всех `input` под каждый из которых вешается addEventListener. Мне кажется это не совсем рационально. Особенно если input-ов очень много(порядка 50). И, наверное, дольше, чем во втором способе.

**Второй спопоб**, на мой взгляд намного удобнее, когда производится клик и если этот клик по нужному нам объекту, то устанавливается  его значение.

Подскажите, в чем вы видите разницу. Какой бы способ вы предпочли и почему? 
Или, может быть, предложите свой вариант. Спасибо!

Comment: _Везде вижу только первый способ_ - где например?

Comment: @Grundy, Первый это самый первый под HTML кодом в моем вопросе

Comment: я имел ввиду, где именно везде ты видишь только первый способ?

Comment: @Grundy я как-то задавал несколько однотипных вопросов на этом сайте, мне ответили столько же первым способом. В документации на сайтах по javascript тоже в основном встречал  первый способ. А про второй такое ощущение, что я сам догадался!)

Comment: в ответах его используют просто потому, что писать быстрее

Comment: @Grundy Но удобней ведь второй? Он более понятный, более логичный и быстрый. Это так?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45889/discussion-between-grundy-and-pavel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второй способ называется [делегированием](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation).
И его рациональнее использовать с достаточно большим количеством однотипных слушателей.
Преимущества очевидны - меньше памяти занимает, проще отлаживать. Но бывает сложновато реализовать грамотно. Поэтому 1-2 элемента можно и первым способом реализовать.
Для всего остального есть MasterCard, т. е. делегирование.

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от конкретной постановки задачи.

Предположим у нас такая структура

```
<div id="goal">
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <p>...</p>
</div>
```

Предположим `<div>` будет в себе одержать все `<p>` и нам нужны клики по ним. То второй вариант здесь кстати.

А теперь представь такую ситуацию:

```
<div id="goal">
   <p>...</p>
   <span>...</span>
   <p>...</p>
   <span>...</span>
   <p>...</p>
</div>
```

Если нам нужны клики только по `<p>` тегам, то лучше поставить триггеры только на `<p>` тег. Таким образом мы избежим лишних сообщений о кликах по `<span>`. Здесь подойдет первый вариант с выборкой `<p>` тегов.

Есть конкретные ситуации. Например, `div` в себе содержит множество `p`. Если пройтись по for, то все текущие `<p>` будут реагировать на клик. Если после for в один момент в `div` будет добавлен еще один `<p>`, то он не будет реагировать на клик, потому что на нем нет триггера. Но если поступить как во втором варианте, то сколько бы `<p>` мы не добавляли в `<div>` все они будут кликабельны, поскольку у нас событие прикреплено на `div`.

Comment: проблема определения по чему щелкнули решается проверкой event.target, поэтому лишних сообщений не будет

Comment: Я расширил ответ.

Comment: @Grundy вопрос звучал так "Подскажите, в чем вы видите разницу. Какой бы способ вы предпочли и почему? Или, может быть, предложите свой вариант. Спасибо!" А не почему он видит только первый вариант. Pavel хочет увидеть конкретную разницу между двумя вариантами я их описал.